# How do I change the name Ubuntu gives my phone?

Tags: ubuntu, android

When I mount my android phone (HTC Desire, running Froyo) it shows up in the files system mounted in the /media/ directory.  It used to come up as AEA9-A57F (or something similar).  However now it comes up as "Ex\f24 " (yes that's a line feed character).  Which is a little inconvenient as a path, as it means I can't navigate there in the terminal among other things.

How can I change the name given to the drive?

Thanks heaps :D

Comment: `cd /media/Ex`<TAB>

Comment: \f is (almost always) form feed, while \n is line feed.

Answer (score 1):

I *would* go and say that you should reformat the drive, but since this is a phone, that's probably not a safe option.
[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive) guide in Ubuntu should work, but before you try, back up and make sure you have some sort of Plan B if the thing accidentally formats your phone.